# How to convert the dynamically produced array object data into JSON format string in golang?

Tags: go

On the data retrieval the data is in the form of array object like this:

```
[{1 fruits Apple Apple is my favorite fruit.} {2 colors Red Red color is always charming.} {3 flowers Lotus It is one of the most beautiful flowers in this world.}]
```

how will I change it in JSON. I just need to break the array object braces [].

I have tried to `Marshal` it. But It gives me like:

```
[{"id":1,"category":"fruits","name":"Apple","description":"Apple is my favorite fruit."},{"id":2,"category":"colors","name":"Red","description":"Red color is always charming."},{"id":3,"category":"flowers","name":"Lotus","description":"It is one of the most beautiful flowers in this world."}]
```

The code I'd tried

Struct

```
type Item struct {
 Id          int    `json:"id"`
 Category    string `json:"category"`
 Name        string `json:"name"`
 Description string `json:"description"`
} 
type Items []Item
```

Here the function for retrieving data

```
func GetData(productQuery interface{}) (result Items, err error) {
 mongoSession := ConnectDb()
 sessionCopy := mongoSession.Copy()
 defer sessionCopy.Close()
 getCollection := mongoSession.DB("custom").C("custom")
 err = getCollection.Find(productQuery).Select(bson.M{"password": 0}).All(&result) //.Skip(skip).Limit(limit)
 if err != nil {
    return result, err
 }
 return result, nil
}
/*
 *
 *  Retrieve the data used by main function
 *
 *
 */

func retrieve(c *gin.Context) {
  conditions := bson.M{}
  data, err :=GetData(conditions)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("There is somthing wrong")
  }
  fmt.Println("--------------------")
  fmt.Println(data)
  fmt.Println("--------------------")
  arrange(data)
  return
}   

func arrange(data Items) { 
  pagesJson, err := json.Marshal(data)
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal("Cannot encode to JSON ", err)
  }
  fmt.Println(string(pagesJson))
}
```

I want to make the output like

```
{"id": 1,"category": "fruits","name": "Apple","description": "Apple is my favorite fruit."} {"id": 2,"category": "colors","name": "Red",description": "Red color is always charming."} {"id": 3,"category": "flowers","name": "Lotus","description": "It is one of the most beautiful flowers in this world."}
```

can anyone help me I tried it lot of times but don't take any success.

Comment: `{1 fruits Apple Apple is my favorite fruit.}` is not valid JSON, so you cannot expect to use the `json` package to parse or generate it.

Comment: thanku for replying but i edit my question

Comment: Obviously, iterate over the slice and marshal each element.

Comment: I am new on golang can you please explain it for me?

Comment: 1. Create a struct which can marshal one element of json array say `type struct T` 2. Marshal the json in []T 3. Now just iterate over slices and print as you want

Comment: what you want as the end result is not a valid json, do you understand that? do you need the result in json format?

Comment: Yes sir i need the result in json format

Comment: is there is any method to solve this????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will works

```
package main

import (
  "bytes"
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "strings"
)

type Item struct {
  Id          int    `json:"id"`
  Category    string `json:"category"`
  Name        string `json:"name"`
  Description string `json:"description"`
}

type Items []Item

var myJson = []byte(`[{
 "id":1,
 "category":"fruits",
 "name":"Apple",
 "description":"Apple is my favorite fruit."
},
{
 "id":2,
 "category":"colors",
 "name":"Red",
 "description":"Red color is always charming."
},
{
 "id":3,
 "category":"flowers",
 "name":"Lotus",
 "description":"It is one of the most beautiful flowers in this world."
}]`)

func main() {
    var items Items

    err := json.Unmarshal(myJson, &items)
    if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
    }

    s, err := getMyString(items)
   if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
   }

   fmt.Println(s)
}

func getMyString(items Items) (string, error) {
  var buffer bytes.Buffer
  var err error
  var b []byte

  for _, item := range items {
    b, err = json.Marshal(item)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    buffer.WriteString(string(b) + " ")
  }

  s := strings.TrimSpace(buffer.String())

  return s, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply encode each element of your slice individually:

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "log"
        "os"
)

type T struct {
        ID          int    `json:"id"`
        Category    string `json:"category"`
        Name        string `json:"name"`
        Description string `json:"description"`
}

func main() {
        var data []T

        enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
        for _, x := range data {
                if err := enc.Encode(x); err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: the data i retrieved is type of interface. It gives me error `cannot range over data (type interface {})`.

Comment: Don't store your data in an empty interface{} if you want to work with it later. Since you haven't shown how you retrieve it I can't help you with that.

Comment: The data you retrieve is not of type interface{} it is of type Items. change `func arrange(data interface{})` to `func arrange(data Items)`.

Comment: i changed it but the problem is same :(. I m trying it from one and half day:(

Comment: can you help me ?

Comment: @Puneet, I don't know what else to tell you. If you haven't done so yet, [take the Tour](https://tour.golang.org). Perhaps that will clear things up.