# How to convert the array object data to string format data using golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

There is an **array object** which is retrieved from mongodb. The data looks like below:-

```
[{
  1 
  fruits 
  Apple 
  Apple is my favorite fruit.
 }
 {
  2 
  colors 
  Red 
  Red color is always charming.
 } 
 {
  3 
  flowers 
  Lotus 
  It is one of the most beautiful flowers in this world.
 }]
```

This is the code for retrieving the above data 
The struct is:

```
type Item struct {
  Id          int    `json:"id"`
  Category    string `json:"category"`
  Name        string `json:"name"`
  Description string `json:"description"`
}
type Items []Item

func GetData(Query interface{}) (result Items, err error) {
    mongoSession := ConnectDb()
    sessionCopy := mongoSession.Copy()
    defer sessionCopy.Close()
    getCollection := mongoSession.DB("custom").C("custom")
    err = getCollection.Find(Query).All(&result)
    if err != nil {
        return result, err
    }
    return result, nil
}
/*
 *  Retrieve the data used by main function
 */
func retrieve(c *gin.Context) {
  //mongoSession := ConnectDb()
  conditions := bson.M{}
  data, err :=GetData(conditions)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("There is somthing wrong")
  }
  arrange(data)
  return
}

func arrange(data Items) {
  pagesJson, err := json.Marshal(data)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Cannot encode to JSON ", err)
  }
  fmt.Println(string(pagesJson))
}
```

Running `json.Marshal`, the output looks like below:

```
[{
  "id":1,
  "category":"fruits",
  "name":"Apple",
  "description":"Apple is my favorite fruit."
},
{
  "id":2,
  "category":"colors",
  "name":"Red",
  "description":"Red color is always charming."
},
{
  "id":3,
  "category":"flowers",
  "name":"Lotus",
  "description":"It is one of the most beautiful flowers in this world."
}]
```

Expected output

```
{
  "id":1,
  "category":"fruits",
  "name":"Apple",
  "description":"Apple is my favorite fruit."
}
{
  "id":2,
  "category":"colors",
  "name":"Red",
  "description":"Red color is always charming."
}
{
  "id":3,
  "category":"flowers",
  "name":"Lotus",
  "description":"It is one of the most beautiful flowers in this world."
}
```

The issue is the data is in the array object for my use I need the String structure data between `{}` as shown above. I posted this question before but not getting any success answer. I am trying it from a lot of time help me thankyou.

Comment: Hi @Puneet, what is your expected output? and also, the data retrieved from mongodb that you're saying doesn't look valid to me.

Comment: @srf then what should i do for it help me i m new in golang. can you help me?

Comment: I will try my best, can you describe your use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert the dynamically produced array object data into JSON format in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669922/how-to-convert-the-dynamically-produced-array-object-data-into-json-format-in-go)

Comment: There is no reason to post your question twice. If you want to clarify something, edit your existing question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what OP has discussed, marshaling the struct `Items` would give this:

```
[{
  "id":1,
  "category":"fruits",
  "name":"Apple",
  "description":"Apple is my favorite fruit."
},
{
  "id":2,
  "category":"colors",
  "name":"Red",
  "description":"Red color is always charming."
},
{
  "id":3,
  "category":"flowers",
  "name":"Lotus",
  "description":"It is one of the most beautiful flowers in this world."
}]
```

From this, OP wants to get a string that looks like this:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "category":"fruits",
  "name":"Apple",
  "description":"Apple is my favorite fruit."
},
{
  "id":2,
  "category":"colors",
  "name":"Red",
  "description":"Red color is always charming."
},
{
  "id":3,
  "category":"flowers",
  "name":"Lotus",
  "description":"It is one of the most beautiful flowers in this world."
}
```

There are two approaches that I considered:

1. Looping through items and appending each marshaled items into a string (clearly not efficient)

   ```
   func getMyString(items Items) (string, error) {

       var buffer bytes.Buffer
       var err error
       var b []byte

       for _, item := range items {
           b, err = json.Marshal(item)
           if err != nil {
               return "", err
           }

           buffer.WriteString(string(b) + ",")
       }

       s := strings.TrimSpace(buffer.String())
       // trim last comma
       s = s[:len(s)-1]

       return s, nil
   }
   ```
2. Or just trimming off the leading and trailing square brackets:

   ```
   func getMyString2(items Items) (string, error) {

       b, err := json.Marshal(items)
       if err != nil {
           return "", err
       }

       s := string(b)
       s = strings.TrimSpace(s)
       // trim leading and trailing spaces
       s = s[1 : len(s)-1]
       return s, nil
   }
   ```

Link to code: https://play.golang.org/p/F1SUYJZEn_n

**EDIT:** Since OP want it to be space separated, I've modified approach number 1 to fit the requirements:

```
func getMyString(items Items) (string, error) {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    var err error
    var b []byte

    for _, item := range items {
        b, err = json.Marshal(item)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        // use space to separate each json string in the array
        buffer.WriteString(string(b) + " ")
    }

    s := strings.TrimSpace(buffer.String())

    return s, nil
}
```

Link to new code: https://play.golang.org/p/dVvsQlsRqZO

Comment: sir every thing is awsome but one thing is giving me error that the string is separated by the comma can it would be a space . see comma after the `}` pranthese